# Arno Pro and LaTex/pdfLateX

Tags: fonts, adobe

Is it possible to use Adobe Arno Pro as a font in LaTex/pdfLatex? [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) provides scripts (on the basis of the [LCDF](http://www.lcdf.org/type/)-tool) to convert Minon Pro otfs and to use them with texlive. According to [John Owens Website](http://web.ece.ucdavis.edu/~jowens/code/otfinst/) it's possible to use the roughly the same with the LCDF tool -- is there a tutorial (step-by-step) or maybe a script (like for Minion Pro), to create all necessary files for LaTeX? (I'm a aware that it's possible to use otf-fonts with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX -- but I'm interested in using Arno Pro with pdfLaTeX)

Comment: The chapter [“Using OpenType Fonts” of Marc van Dongen's “LaTeX and Friends”](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-23816-1_16) entails a nice guide on how to convert OpenType fonts for use with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What's preventing you from doing the easy thing and just using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? With either of these engines and with the `fontspec` package, you'll have full access to all font features of `Arno Pro` -- something you won't have if you convert an opentype font for use with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Without work, you won't get the best results from a conversion using these tools. You'll get something reasonable, but setting up a font support package can be automated only by forgoing the things you do to fine-tune the support to the particular fonts you've got. (I don't mean the conversion can't be scripted - I mean that the script needs to be specific to the fonts for best results.) Xe/LuaLaTeX with **fontspec** will give you better results without fine-tuning, and access to features which even the best fine-tuning can't enable. (This is not to say there are no losses. There are.)

Comment: it's just some features of Microtype that hold me back (and maybe some package in my thesis that might not work) but I'm actually using @Mico LuaLaTeX to create plots via the externalize command and for smaller documents (like letters) or beamer-presentations.  Additionally, LuaLaTeX is rather slow but of course there great features, too. Like your `selnolig`-package and ℝaphink's `homeoarchy`-package etc.

Comment: @harryhaller - Many thanks for the compliment about the `selnolig` package. :-) These days, most features of the `microtype` package work equally well under pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX; the main difference is that extra fine-tuning of kerning and spacing is currently not (yet) enabled for LuaLaTeX. As cfr has already noted, an awful lot of work will be required by you if you want to to get some of the niftier capabilities of the Arno Pro opentype font to work under pdfLaTeX, whereas they will be available "out of the box" when you use the `fontspec` package.

Comment: @harryhaller Concerning speed you might want to take a look at `luajittex`.  The built-in just-in-time compiler for Lua speeds up Lua-heavy code by 10% to 40% (source [ConTeXt Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Running_Mark_IV#Experimental_speedup)).